# Updates to a rectangles co-ordinates not being registered in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to teach myself to code in pygame and currently making a simple game for a home project. I have written the code thinking that it should update the player's rectangle's co-ordinates every iteration of the game loop, based on the player's inputs. However, the rectangle's co-ordinates are being reset, rather than changed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

##Set up the colours
WHITE =(255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 165, 0)
PINK = (255, 192, 203)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
KHAKI = (189, 183, 107)
MAGENTA = (255, 0, 255)

##Set up the window
WINDOWHEIGHT = 500
WINDOWWIDTH = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tower')


##Set up level variable    
level = 1

##Run game loop
while True:
    ##Check for quit event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()


    ##Check for level
    if level == 1:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        MOVESPEED = 10

    ##Enemy rectangles
        e1 = pygame.Rect(200, 0, 50, 100)
        e2 = pygame.Rect(250, 50, 50, 100) 
        e3 = pygame.Rect(300, 100, 50, 100)
        e4 = pygame.Rect(450, 250, 50, 100)
        e5 = pygame.Rect(500, 300, 50, 100)
        e6 = pygame.Rect(550, 350, 50, 100)

        enemies = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6]

    ##Draw enemy rectangles
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e1, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e2, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e3, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e4, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e5, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e6, 0)

    ##Player rectangle
        player = pygame.Rect(25, 25, 50, 50)

    ##Change keyboard variables

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveDown = False    
    ##Move the player with the keyboard

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                player.left -= MOVESPEED
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                player.top += MOVESPEED
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                player.left += MOVESPEED
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                player.top -= MOVESPEED

    ##Check if player is in the window
        if player.top < 0:
    #The player has moved past the top
            player.top += 1

        if player.bottom > WINDOWHEIGHT:
    #The player has moved past the bottom
            player.top -= 1

        if player.left < 0:
    #The player has moved past the left side
            player.left += 1

        if player.right > WINDOWWIDTH:
    #The player has moved past the right side
            player.left -= 1

    #Draw player onto the screen
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, player)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: A little tip: Draw the enemy rectangles with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining enemies and player at each loop iteration again and again. You need to define them once. Then update and draw them in the loop. This is the solution of your problem.

I tried your code with some changes. For simplicity, I deleted the parts you don't use so far and combined some if conditions.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys

from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit


#SET UP
pygame.init()

WHITE =(255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

WINDOWHEIGHT = 500
WINDOWWIDTH = 1000
MOVESPEED = 10

e1 = pygame.Rect(200, 0, 50, 100)
e2 = pygame.Rect(250, 50, 50, 100) 
e3 = pygame.Rect(300, 100, 50, 100)
e4 = pygame.Rect(450, 250, 50, 100)
e5 = pygame.Rect(500, 300, 50, 100)
e6 = pygame.Rect(550, 350, 50, 100)

player = pygame.Rect(25, 25, 50, 50)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tower')

##GAME LOOP
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a) and player.left > MOVESPEED:
                player.left -= MOVESPEED
                player.right -= MOVESPEED

            if (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d) and player.right < WINDOWWIDTH - MOVESPEED:
                player.left += MOVESPEED
                player.right += MOVESPEED

            if (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s) and player.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT - MOVESPEED:
                player.top += MOVESPEED
                player.bottom += MOVESPEED

            if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w) and player.top > MOVESPEED:
                player.top -= MOVESPEED
                player.bottom -= MOVESPEED

    #DRAW SCREEN AT EACH ITERATION
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e1, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e2, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e3, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e4, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e5, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, e6, 0)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, player)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I hadn't thought of combining the 'if' conditions as well.